# Simplifying a formula and making it more flexible to adjust if Tabs are deleted

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Since I'v received such a helpful reply to another question so that, I thought I'd reach out to you super smart folks again.

I've created this following formula which works:

```
=(SUMIF(MoF!L7:L48,"<5")+SUMIF(RA!L7:L47,"<5")+SUMIF(Par!L9:L16,"<5")+SUMIF('MDA-1'!L8:L44,"<5")+SUMIF('MDA-2'!L8:L44,"<5")+SUMIF('MDA-3'!L8:L44,"<5")+SUMIF(#REF!L8:L44,"<5")+SUMIF(#REF!L8:L44,"<5"))/(COUNT(MoF!L7:L48)+COUNT(RA!L7:L47)+COUNT(Par!L9:L16)+COUNT('MDA-1'!L8:L44)+COUNT('MDA-2'!L8:L44)+COUNT('MDA-3'!L8:L44)+COUNT(#REF!L8:L44)+COUNT(#REF!L8:L44))
```

The purpose of this formula is to `Sum` a set of cells in 5 different `Tabs` and then divide this `Sum` by the number of cells that have numbers in them. Basically I'm averaging the values in these cells, but there are multiple different ranges so this is how I figured out to do it.

The problem is that one or two of the tabs might not be used/populated and will therefore be deleted from the workbook, which results in a REF error. Is there another way to do this formula so that it automatically adjusts when the tabs are deleted?

Comment: if you want single formula for the `SUMIF` across the Wokbook **then Data Range Must be similar in all Sheet**. I can suggest you single formula to calculate conditional Average across the Workbook **but if you can adjust the data in similar Range in all sheets**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel has a built in function called `IFERROR` that can replace a `REF#` error with any value you want.

`=IFERROR(value, value if error)` is the basic usage.

You probably want to wrap one of these around each formula that *could* return an error if it references something that does not exist yet. It looks like that would be the `SUMIF` blocks in your formula, so they would probably end up something like this:

`=IFERROR(SUMIF(..., ...), 0)`

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Thank you so much! I used the following and it works perfectly:=(SUMIF(MoF!L7:L48,"<5")+SUMIF(RA!L7:L47,"<5")+SUMIF(Par!L9:L16,"<5")+IFERROR(SUMIF('MDA-1'!L8:L44,"<5"),0)+IFERROR(SUMIF('MDA-2'!L8:L44,"<5"),0)+IFERROR(SUMIF('MDA-3'!L8:L44,"<5"),0)+IFERROR(SUMIF('MDA-4'!L8:L44,"<5"),0)+IFERROR(SUMIF('MDA-5'!L8:L44,"<5"),0))/(COUNT(MoF!L7:L48)+COUNT(RA!L7:L47)+COUNT(Par!L9:L16)+IFERROR(COUNT('MDA-1'!L8:L44),0)+IFERROR(COUNT('MDA-2'!L8:L44),0)+IFERROR(COUNT('MDA-3'!L8:L44),0)+IFERROR(COUNT('MDA-4'!L8:L44),0)+IFERROR(COUNT('MDA-5'!L8:L44),0))

Comment: @Shamiso, if his answer is correct (it is!) Accept the answer

Comment: @Shamiso Also, you may want to post an answer to your own question if you have an answer.